# What is the difference between SpringResourceTemplateResolver and ClassLoaderTemplateResolver?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to cofigure my project. I have two variants of tempalteResolver.
if i use this one:

```
 @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
        return templateResolver;
    }
```

i get an error that my template can't resolve the thymeleaf syntax th even when i add xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"

and when i use the following code:

```
  @Bean
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return templateResolver;
    }
```

i get an error that there is no templates under this path (/WEB-INF/templates).

Full path to my templates is src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\templates\

What is the best template resolver to be used and why?

Thanks!

Comment: Without actual error messages, there is nothing to debug.  You should be using `SpringResourceTemplateResolver` for web projects (using SpringMvc controllers), and `ClassLoaderTemplateResolver` for command line projects, or when you need to generate html for non-web applications (such as sending html email or something like that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You should be using SpringResourceTemplateResolver for web projects (using SpringMvc controllers), and ClassLoaderTemplateResolver for command line projects, or when you need to generate html for non-web applications (such as sending html email or something like that).

First error occured becouse spring security somehow didn't connect to a project and my

```
 Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
modelAndView.addObject("auth", auth);
```

Send nulls.
And second error i dunno why occured.